# Get Objects Not Transacted for Last 3 Months

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django. I have two objects in a django project: *Transaction* and *Item*. Item can have many Transaction objects. Transaction has *date_time* and *item* fields. How can I write a django query to fetch Items that haven't had any transactions in the past 20 days?

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your model and view codes.

Comment: Hi Basar, I have shown the models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your models are:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

You can do a query like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Item.objects.distinct().exclude(transaction__created_at__gte=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=20))
```

This query will find items with transactions in past 20 days, then show rest of the items (which dont have any transaction in past 20 days).

Try this on Django Shell. To open shell: `python manage.py shell`

Comment: What version of Django are you using? `import django` `django.VERSION` should give you version.

Comment: @Teddy can you please copy and paste the exact command that gave you this error?

Comment: There's no field named `transaction` in `Item` model.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships `It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.`

Comment: @jerrymouse if there has been a transaction both before and after 20 days, the Item will still show up but all I need is only the Items that haven't had any transaction in the last 20 days

Comment: @Teddy I have updated the answer which works like you desire.

Comment: @jerrymouse thank you for the answer. Just to ask as an additional question, can I get the date_time for the last transaction of each item fetched from the query? I would really appreciate your help